# Bad Request with multiple URLs using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape 3 products on a website. I have attached all 3 into a `.txt` file.

When running, for some reason I get a "`Bad Request`" on the first 2 URLs and it successfully scraps the 3rd URL and sends a webhook to discord. No matter what order I put the URLs it only seems to do the last URL, whether I do it with proxies or not. (I added proxies as I want to do a lot more URLs than just the 3.)

Here is my current code:

```
import requests
import lxml.html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from dhooks import Webhook, Embed
import random

ua = UserAgent()
header = {'User-Agent':ua.chrome}

# Proxies
proxy_list = []

for line in open('proxies.txt', 'r'):
    line = line.replace('\n', '')
    proxy_list.append(line)

def get_proxy():
    proxy = random.choice(proxy_list)
    proxies = {
        "http": f'{str(proxy)}',
        "https": f'{str(proxy)}'
    }
    return proxies

# Opening URL file 
with open('urls.txt','r') as file:
    for url in file.readlines():
        proxies = get_proxy()
        result = requests.get(url,headers=header,timeout=3,proxies=proxies)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'lxml')
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: may be the first two urls are not well formed

Comment: They are the same format as the last one, I even switched their positions and is still does the last url no matter what is there. I tried adding 10 urls, it did Bad Request for the first 9 and successfully did the 10th.

Comment: what happen if you only give one url

Comment: It successfully scraps that URL and sends the embed to discord.

Comment: `requests.get(url.strip() ,headers=header,timeout=3,proxies=proxies)`

Comment: Oh wow that worked! But now the issue I have is only the last product is sent to discord

Comment: Actually I fixed that